# C++ creating different constructors

Tags: c++

I´m writing sequence for **oscilloscopes** and want to have  constructor with different objects depending on a scope used.

So  I want to create constructor with objects mentioned below depending on  a scope, instead of creating different constructors.
So for example, for one scope I need only polarity range and width so I take objects from list and dynamically create constructor.

Is that possible?

```
ScopeTriggerWidth::ScopeTriggerWidth(AnsiString polarity, AnsiString range, double width, double delta, AnsiString source, double upper_value, double lower_value)
```

Sorry if my explanation is not clear, this is my first time here.

Comment: Unclear, showing different expected usages may improve that.

Comment: When you say "scope" do you mean "oscilloscope"? Or "scope" in the C++ sense of the word?

Comment: Nice joke! :) I believe both are right

Comment: I want to have  one class called ScopeTriggerWidth with different constructors and I want to use the classs with different objects  depending on the scope I use

For oscilloscope A it can be 

   ScopeTriggerWidth::ScopeTriggerWidth(AnsiString , AnsiString , double , double )

For another one with more or less objects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When default parameters don't fit your needs, e.g. because you need to be able to set one of the later parameters without setting one before, try something similar to the named parameters idiom (beware: untested code, that will probably not even compile):

```
class ScopeTriggerWithParams {
    private:
         const AnsiString& polarity_;
         const AnsiString& range_;
         double width_ = 4711;
         double delta_ = 42;
         AnsiString source_ = "asdfasdf"s;
         double upper_value_ = 815;
         double lower_value_ = 23;
    public:
         ScopeTriggerWithParams(const AnsiString& polarity,
                                const AnsiString& range):
         polarity_{polarity}, range_{range} {};

         ScopeTriggerWithParams& width(double w) {
             width_ = w;
             return *this;
         };
         ScopeTriggerWithParams& delta(double d) {
             delta_ = d;
             return *this;
         };
         ScopeTriggerWithParams& source(const AnsiString& s) {
             source_ = s;
             return *this;
         };
         // ... 
};

class ScopeTriggerWith {
    // ...
    public:
         ScopeTriggerWith(const ScopeTriggerWithParams& params);
    // ...
};

// ...
auto myScopeTriggerWith =
    ScopeTriggerWith{ScopeTriggerWithParams{"asdf"s, "qwer"s}
                         .delta(42.7)
                         .source("blabla"s)};
```

On the other hand, why are multiple constructors not an option? With C++11 they can defer to one actual constructor implementation.

## Typed Parameters

From the discussion below there is another solution available: typed parameters. Here is a (untested) code example:

```
class Width {
    private:
        double w_;
    public:
        Width() = delete;
        Width(const double w): w_{w} {};
        Width(const Width& w): w_{w.w_} {};

        operator double () const { return w_; };
        Width& operator = (const double w) {
            w_ = w;
            return *this;
        };
        Width& operator = (const Width& w) {
            w_ = w.w_;
            return *this;
        };
};

class Delta {
    private:
        double d_;
    public:
        Delta() = delete;
        Delta(const double d): d_{d} {};
        Delta(const Delta& d): d_{d.d_} {};

        operator double () const { return d_; };
        Delta& operator = (const double d) {
            d_ = d;
            return *this;
        };
        Delta& operator = (const Delta& d) {
            d_ = d.d_;
            return *this;
        };
};

class Source {
    private:
        AnsiString s_;
    public:
        Source() = delete;
        Source(const AnsiString& s): s_{s} {};
        Source(const Source& s): s_{s.s_} {};

        operator double () const { return s_; };
        Source& operator = (const AnsiString& s) {
            s_ = s;
            return *this;
        };
        Source& operator = (const Source& s) {
            s_ = s.s_;
            return *this;
        };
};

class UpperValue {
    private:
        double u_;
    public:
        UpperValue() = delete;
        UpperValue(const double u): u_{u} {};
        UpperValue(const UpperValue& u): u_{u.u_} {};

        operator double () const { return u_; };
        UpperValue& operator = (const double u) {
            u_ = u;
            return *this;
        };
        UpperValue& operator = (const UpperValue& u) {
            u_ = u.u_;
            return *this;
        };
};

class LowerValue {
    private:
        double l_;
    public:
        LowerValue() = delete;
        LowerValue(const double l): l_{l} {};
        LowerValue(const LowerValue& l): l_{l.l_} {};

        operator double () const { return l_; };
        LowerValue& operator = (const double l) {
            l_ = l;
            return *this;
        };
        LowerValue& operator = (const LowerValue& l) {
            l_ = l.l_;
            return *this;
        };
};

class ScopeTriggerWith {
    // ...
    public:
         ScopeTriggerWith(AnsiString polarity, AnsiString range, Width width, Delta delta);
         ScopeTriggerWith(AnsiString polarity, AnsiString range, UpperValue upper_value, LowerValue lower_value);
    // ...
};

// ...
auto myScopeTriggerWith =
    ScopeTriggerWith{"asdf"s, "qwer"s, Width{47.11}, Delta{42.0}};
```

Comment: I do not like multiple constructors because for different oscilloscopes more or less the structure will be like 

    ScopeTriggerWidth::ScopeTriggerWidth(AnsiString , AnsiString , double , double )

and compiler says that this constructor already exists

Comment: I see. In that case you can use typed parameters: `ScopeTriggerWidth(Polarity polarity, Range range, Width width, Delta delta, Source source, UpperValue upper_value, LowerValue lower_value) ` All these Types just encapsulate the original value. You can make them implicitly constructable from and convertible to double, so that you can use them as a drop in replacement. Then of course `ScopeTriggerWidth(Polarity polarity, Range range, Width width, Delta delta) ` and `ScopeTriggerWidth(Polarity polarity, Range range, UpperValue upper_value, LowerValue lower_value) ` are different constructors.

Comment: When you use the Typed Parameters, you'll have to add the typenames to help the compiler distinguish the constructors: `ScopeTrigggerWidth{"asdf"s, "asdf"s, Width{4711}, Delta{42}};`

Comment: Thanks very much for that. So basicall y this typed parameters will be like a storage for all parameters?
The last question is will it be ok to create something like `ScopeTriggerWidth()` and then create the constructor I need with `new` I´m just reading about that and for me it is really complicated, is it really worth that?

Comment: I guess, only you can judge, weather it is worth the effort.

Comment: When you need this pattern more often, I think, a generic templated solution is possible, so that you only have to write something like e.g. `class Width: public TypedParameter<double, Width> {};` to create a new typed parameter class. I have not tried now, but I think it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

If you parameter lists may form a same-prefix sequence, like (A,B), (A,B,C), (A,B,C,D,E) then you may have one constructor with default values when needed, like

```
MyClass(A a, B b, C c=default_c, D d=default_d, E e=default_e);
```

But if you want also say (A,E) than you will be to create another constructor.